# multiple ngFor is not working angular 4

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to populate chunked results using ngFor

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of states; let i = index">
                    <ul>
                        <li ngFor="let state of item">{{item}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

If i populate item, i am getting this
[image]

**The chunked results are converted to string**

If i try populating state

```
<div *ngFor="let item of states; let i = index">
                    <ul>
                        <li ngFor="let state of item">{{state}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I get a blank output.

If * is used before second ngFor

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of states; let i = index">
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let state of item">{{state}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I get error as following[image]

How can i chunk and populate the values?

**Edit-1 & 2**

Here is my data that is passed to ngFor (edit 2 as expanded object)
[image]

**Edit 3**
Here is my html output. The data is populating as string if i use

```
<div class="split-by-4">
                <div *ngFor="let item of states; let i = index">
                    <ul>
                        <li ngFor="let state of item[i]">{{item}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Working answer (actually my mistake)**

```
{
$("#cities-with-state-modal").modal('open');

    this.chunkStates();
}
chunkStates(){
    this.states = _.cloneDeep(this.backup.states); // this.states is loading and its giving as string before the data got chunked.
    let chunkSize = _.toInteger(this.states.length/4);
    this.statesChunk = _.chunk(this.states, chunkSize);
  }
```

**html**

```
<div class="split-by-4" *ngIf="statesChunk && statesChunk.length">
                <div *ngFor="let item of statesChunk; let i = index">
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let state of item">{{state.name}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Well we don't even know how your data looks like? You are trying to iterate something that is not an array, and btw use `*ngFor` :)

Comment: I have updated the console.log of this.states @AJT_82

Comment: @AJT_82 All he needs to do is add  a dot to the field.`{{state.myField}}`. there is nothing wrong with ngFor on array of arrays with a nested ngFor

Comment: @Royi, I have suspected from the beginning that it's an property, but I want OP to give enough information, to perhaps get a decent answer ;)

Comment: @Royi I was set on that error was that it wasn't an array containing arrays that I got blind, I just saw an array with objects. Now I see it's an array with arrays :D Ugh, maybe I need a break :D

Comment: If i put state.name its throwing me error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. You could see that no output is populated if i  put {{state}} only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo :

You forgot an asterix in `<li ngFor`. ( hence the error).

Also -

You are iterating an array of arrays of **objects**. so you need a prop at the end.

The difference : see `{{state.MyStateProperty}}`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of states; let i = index">
   <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let state of item">{{state.MyStateProperty}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[**Here's a basic working plnkr  representing your nested structure.**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VrNv5RWffGHEty1W3JYZ)

Comment: If i add * its throwing error. Can you please recheck again my console error

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You should use `*` as `*ngFor` - otherwise things won't work. see the plunkr

Comment: I am using angular 4 and if you note my developer tool output, the item is converted to string. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene My plunker is also with Angular4. can you paste your final code ? I want to see the FINAL code you used.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Please closely compare your final code with the code Royi gave you... what's the difference? ;)

Comment: I copy pasted his code, renamed arr with states and state.a as state.name, i get the error as posted.

Comment: Well couldn't have copy pasted it, since they are not the same. `state.a` and `state.name` is not the only difference ;)

Comment: I got it. I will post the answer

Comment: Well, Royi has posted the correct answer, so you should accept his/hers :) Didn't BTW mean to bug you, so hopefully you didn't get annoyed. Just wanted you to perhaps realize the error yourself, using the index, you were actually trying to iterate each object of the inner array instead of the inner array :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you.